# Possible to make overlay view scree-wide over 2 different elements?

Tags: android, android-layout, overlay

I have a layout looking like this.

[image]

The bottom part are the tabs and this is one of the tabs. It has a `LinerLayout` on the left and `ListView` on the right side. The list view goes beyond screen height and elements are scrollable.

Is it possible to locate red-colored `LayoutView` over these element at this specific location without much redesigning a layout?

Comment: If the `LinearLayout` and the `ListView` are in a `RelativeLayout` then it should be easy.

Comment: Hm "easy". How? I cannot use `below` as ListView item goes all the way down (not all are visible)

Comment: Well, I'm not sure about the tabs, but cant you use `above` with the tabs or aligned to the bottom of the screen?

Comment: @Urban Can you explain more your idea? thanks